# svg mask on jpg not working

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
  .masked-element {
    mask-image: url(images-free-tour/cauldron/mask.svg);
    mask-mode: alpha;
  }
   .masked-element image {
    mask: url(images-free-tour/cauldron/mask.svg);
    mask-mode: alpha;
  }
</style>
```

And here is the image in the body of the page

```
    <img class="masked element" src="images-free-tour/cauldron/cauldron-angel-640.jpg" />
```

I've tried doing this lots of different ways none of them work, the mask is supposed to allow the page background through, it doesn't.  Help!

Comment: What element is `.masked-element image` intended to refer to?

Comment: Just me trying different syntax from tutorials to try and do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, where you are going wrong is, not testing in Firefox (which is [the only browser that supports it](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask)).

Chrome and Safari have limited support via the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. Microsoft browsers do not currently support it at all.

---

Additionally, the selector to match `<img class="masked element">` is `img.masked.element` and not `.masked-element image`.